# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target error is thrown on Instantiating of Class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular2-routing

I am trying to wrap each of `router.navigateByUrl` in a function of a class and plan to call that function in relevant place. But doing so throwing 'Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target'. I have followed few other links in SO but none seems to be helpful in my case

commonRouter.ts

```
 // have wrapped navigation to home in homePage
 // so wherever is needed this homePage will be called instead of 
 //this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');

import {Router} from '@angular/router';
export class RouterComponent{
  router:any;
  constructor(private rt:Router){
    this.router=rt;
  }
  homePage(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }

}
```

someComponent.ts

```
// Importing the newly created typescript file
import {RouterComponent} from './../../app-routing-component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.less']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  private ms:MainService= new MainService();
  //Instantiating RouterComponent
  private rt:RouterComponent = new RouterComponent(); // this line throwing error
  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {}
  someMethod(){
    rt.homePage() // Calling homePage
   }
   //... rest of code
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
// module where all the paths and component are declared
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home/home.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login', component: LoginComponent,

  }, {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
    children: [{
      path: "account",
      component: AccountsComponent
    },{

    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RouterComponent` requires a `Router` argument. Router is an injectable, thus would be resolvable if Angular knows how to handle your RouterComponent class.

It would be best to decorate your class as `Injectable` and inject the value at the Angular component. e.g.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';    
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RouterService {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  homePage(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
  }
};
```

Register it in your module or add as dependency to the providers field in the `Component` decorator and import it into your components.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterService } from '...';

@Component({ ... })
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private router: RouterService) { }

  toHomePage() {
    this.router.homePage();
  }
};
```

Because it is an Injectable, Angular knows how to resolve the parameters.

The choice of namingconvention for your `RouterComponent` class would led others to think it is decorated as an Angular `component`, but you are using it as a `service`.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue , I am learning angular2,will learn about @Injectable

Comment: Just one update RouterComponent need to be added in provider

Comment: That's true, but I've only stated that in the answer and not added to the codebase because you can also register it in your `NgModule` to use it in all your components or the like without having to declare it as provider for all the classes that require on it. However those classes have to be registered to the same module in order for Angular to resolve the injectable paramaters.